# sql query to fetch results via comma seperated

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have 2 tables and wants to fetch all the categories via comma seperated.

```
SELECT object_id, meta_value, name, event_level, event_temp_id FROM 
wp_em_meta, wp_terms, wp_em_events WHERE wp_em_meta.meta_key = 'category-image' 
AND wp_em_meta.object_id IN ($eventtid) AND wp_em_meta.object_id = wp_terms.term_id 
AND wp_em_meta.object_id = wp_em_events.event_temp_id
```

eg:

table 1

---

[image]
    in the image attached, i want to fetch the results as [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in MySQL

```
SELECT object_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(event_level) as meta_value, 
name, event_level, event_temp_id FROM 
wp_em_meta, wp_terms, wp_em_events 
WHERE wp_em_meta.meta_key = 'category-image' 
AND wp_em_meta.object_id IN ($eventtid) AND wp_em_meta.object_id = wp_terms.term_id 
AND wp_em_meta.object_id = wp_em_events.event_temp_id
GROUP BY object_id
```